# Preg_replace to Preg_replace All

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, markdown

Someone was kind enough to help me out with a regex for a very specific use, but my only problem now, is that the regex only replaces **one** instance of the match, and not all *matches* (which is the goal).

I would like **every** instance of the `<SPAN>` with the "stylish-blue-button" class found here :

```
<span class="stylish-blue-button">
   <span style="display:none;">[data-user="12345" data-userId="678910"]</span>
     John Smith
   <span style="display:none;">[/]</span>
</span>
...Blablabla some other text...
```

To become this :

```
[data-user="12345" data-userId="678910"]John Smith[/] ...Blablabla some other text...
```

To do so, I was provided with this preg_replace :

```
preg_replace('~\[(data-user="\d+")\h+(data-userId="\d+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/\]\s*(.*)~s', '<span $1 $2>$3</span>$4', trim(strip_tags($string)));
```

Now this works and it's wonderful, but it only replaces one instance.

**Question :** Would I have to drastically alter/change my approach for it to do so, or would it be a small modification?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool for parsing HTML/XML instead use DOMDocument

Comment: @Uchiha While I completely agree, since the first thing I want to do is execute strip_tags() on the user-generated string, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of trying to parse HTML? Plus, I'd figure, since my custom markdown is going to be very consistent, it wouldn't be the worst thing to do. Do you still think I should push further with DOM Document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$regex = '~\[(data-user="\d+")\s+(data-userId="\d+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[\/\]\s*(.*)~is';

while (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    $string = preg_replace($regex, "&lt;span $1 $2&gt;$3&lt;/span&gt;$4", trim(strip_tags($string)));
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your suggestion, but this does not seem to work unfortunately. Just like the regex in my post, this only replaces the first instance, not all.

Comment: I have used php to get the output as per your example and Tags. You can try this in online tool [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Try function preg_match_all (http://php.net/preg_match_all). I hope its that simple.

Comment: $tags from `preg_match_all('~\[(data-user="\d+")\h+(data-userId="\d+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/\]\s*(.*)~s', strip_tags($string), $tags);` doesn't seem to give me what I want at all unfortunately. Thank you still.